# Docker compose won't push to ECR

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to set up deployment where on `docker compose up` command it would build necessary images, push them to ECR and launch everything on ECS.

What I've done so far.

1. Created and switched to aws context:

```
docker context create ecs aws
docker context use aws
```

2. Created `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    image: <my_aws_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/frontend:latest
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    image: <my_aws_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/backend:latest
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    image: <my_aws_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

After reading a bunch of manuals, to my understanding, command `docker compose up` should:

1. Build images
2. Push them to ECR
3. Create cluster and necessary tasks on ECS
4. Launch containers

Instead I'm having error that telling me that those images are not found. Yes, my ECR repo is empty, but I expect `docker compose up` to build and push images to that repo, not just try to get them from ECR.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of the command is to bring the services `up` locally:

```
❯ docker-compose --help
  ...
  create             Create services
  push               Push service images
  start              Start services
  up                 Create and start containers
```

Depending on context it may as well build and pull images, create or update containers, and of course, start services, but it does not `push`. If you intend to use docker-compose to push images, I suggest you manually run build and push commands:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose push
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! having a problem with `docker-compose` tho: `The platform targeted with the current context is not supported`. `docker compose` looks like doesn't have `build` nor `push` commands, however if i switch to `default` context i can build with `docker compose build` command. It's a bit weird, should I use `default` context to build and push, then switch to `aws` context for `docker compose up`??

Comment: I suspect that you can't build with ECS because you have build files locally, not on ECS. Same goes for `push`, if you build locally, you need to push from local machine, not from ECS. Therefore, you need to build the stuff with a standard context, `docker login` into your ECR (check AWS docs on that, you have to do that only once), then `push`. After that I think you should be able to use your AWS context to bring the stack up.

Answer (score 2):

The `ecs` context in `docker compose` does not allow to build/push. As of today you need to dance slightly between context to achieve what you are trying to do. [This](https://github.com/aws-containers/ecs-anywhere-tutorial/blob/master/app/docker-compose/README.md) is an example (embedded into a completely different project) that shows the process.

In a nutshell (and for posterity):

```
export ACCOUNTNUMBER=<your account>
export MYREGION=<your region>
aws ecr get-login-password --region $MYREGION | docker login --password-stdin --username AWS $ECR_ECSWORKER_REPO_URI 
docker context use default
docker compose build
docker compose push
docker context use myecscontext
docker compose up
```

[the above assumes the `myecscontext` context has already been created with `docker context create ecs myecscontext`]

Comment: thank you very much! that's essentially what i ended up doing, just switching contexts.