# What is the best way to deploy multicontainers to AWS?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I have one docker-compose.yaml which works perfectly on local using `docker compose up` command. Here is the file:

```
version: "2.2"

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    expose:
      - "6379"
  cubestore:
    image: cubejs/cubestore:latest
    environment:
      - CUBESTORE_REMOTE_DIR=/cube/data
    volumes:
      - .cubestore:/cube/data
  **cubejs-api:**
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - CUBEJS_CUBESTORE_HOST=localhost
      - CUBEJS_WEB_SOCKETS=true
      - CUBEJS_DB_TYPE=mysql
      - CUBEJS_API_SECRET=adaJHNIKJGHaaKBDDKJ
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - CUBEJS_REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379
      - DEBUG_LOG=true
      - CUBESTORE_LOG_LEVEL=info
    depends_on:
      - cubestore
      - redis
    links:
      - cubestore
    volumes:
      - .:/cube/conf
      - /cube/conf/node_modules
    working_dir: /cube/conf
```

`cubejs-api` is my main app which connects to other services like redis and cubestore. Now, I want to move this to AWS.

I tried to do it by creating ECS context and ran `docker compose up` command but it failed as it uses Fargate as default and some of the features are not supported in Fargate. So I think I have to use EC2. Other way I tried is, created a image for `cubejs-api` and pushed to ECR and ran it in task under cluster. It worked but I could not add other dependencies(redis and cubestore). I tried to add containers for them in Task Definition along with cubejs-api container but it failed with error.

Can anyone let me know what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in this compose that would not work with Fargate (or put it another way, I don't see how using EC2 could make it easier with this compose as a starting point).

The main issue I see with this compose file is that it maps volumes from your local environment and this can't really work with compose/ECS. I would speculate that if you were able to bake the data straight into the containers (and you'd remove the reference to the volumes in this compose file) it would "just work".

You would still need to dance with the contexts if you want to build the images as part of the compose workflow (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69082852/docker-compose-wont-push-to-ecr)).

There are other alternatives to compose that you could use to deploy to AWS fom a repo with a Dockerfile(s) (such as [Copilot](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/)) but you still need to find a way to embed/bake the data/volumes into the container(s).